# Extract text between characters, strings or brackets

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, replace

## I have following types of data :

```
pd.DataFrame({"Hashtags": [ "[]", "[u'AAPHealthCare4All']", "[u'CBI',","u'Delhi',", "u'Emergency']"]})
```

## Expected Output

```
pd.DataFrame({"Hashtags": [ " ", "AAPHealthCare4All", "CBI","Delhi", "Emergency"]})
```

None of the brackets, parentheses or commas and quotes are missing/typo.
[] should be substituted with blanks. Basically I want to remove all the *"[" , "]" , " [u' "* etc.
I have used the following code, but to no avail :

```
for index,row in df.iterrows(): 
    if "RT @" in row["Tweet"]: 
        df['Hashtags'] =df['Hashtags'].str.replace(r'[^[]]*\[|\][^]*|\[u\'*\'\]|\[\'*\'\]', '')
df.to_csv('string_HT.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can apply the following expression to your hashtags :

```
df['Hashtags'] = sum([x if x else [" "] for x 
                      in ast.literal_eval(''.join(df['Hashtags'])\
                                            .replace('][', '],['))],\
                     [])
```

Result:

```
[' ', 'AAPHealthCare4All', 'CBI', 'Delhi', 'Emergency']
```

However, the number of rows in the dataframe will change, and the indexes will not be preserved. You may be using dataframes incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use extract function:

```
df.Hashtags.str.extract("'(.*)'").fillna('')
Out[1052]: 
0                     
1    AAPHealthCare4All
2                  CBI
3                Delhi
4            Emergency
Name: Hashtags, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

I think simpliset is use double [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) with [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df['Hashtags'] = df['Hashtags'].str.strip("[u,]").str.strip("'").replace('', ' ')
print (df['Hashtags'].tolist())
[' ', 'AAPHealthCare4All', 'CBI', 'Delhi', 'Emergency']
```

Double `strip` is necessary, because if only one, it remove all `u` from starts and ends of strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Hashtags": [ "[]", "[u'uuAAPHealthCare4All']", 
                                "[u'uCBIuu',","u'uDelhi',", "u'Emergency']"]})
print (df)
                   Hashtags
0                        []
1  [u'uuAAPHealthCare4All']
2               [u'uCBIuu',
3                u'uDelhi',
4             u'Emergency']

df['Hashtags'] = df['Hashtags'].str.strip("[u,']")
print (df['Hashtags'])
0                     
1    AAPHealthCare4All
2                  CBI
3                Delhi
4            Emergency
Name: Hashtags, dtype: object
```